Check if a file has been modified since last compile in Overleaf
I have an if-statement that I call in my .tex document in Overleaf
\IfFileExists{mypdf.pdf}
            {\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth}{mypdf.pdf}}
            {\includestandalone[width=1\textwidth]{mypdf}}

which loads a tikz figure that is created in a separate document called mypdf.tex. The if-statement currently only functions as a means to load the pdf image IF the pdf exists already. If not, then it will run the standalone command to generate one. The reason I don't just use the standalone command as-is, is because it takes quite a bit longer to load. In my actual project I have many figures to load so calling standalone on each compile is quite time-consuming. The issue is that if I modify the pdf in the original .tex that new image will not load unless I explicitly call standalone again. As it is, the if-statement would not run the standalone command because the old pdf is still in the directory. I would like to know, using Overleaf how to query whether the mypdf.tex file was updated and use that as the conditional in my if-statement.
I know this all amounts to externalization which there are many questions and answers to, however, I wish to know how to do what I'm asking, regardless of if there is a better way of externalizing (which there likely is). I think it is worth knowing how to check this information and apply it in a conditional statement within the constraints of Overleaf.

The tikz externalization library offers a couple of different strategies how to check if an image needs to be remade. Maybe you can take some inspiration from it for your workflow. Search the tikz user guide for "up to date check" for a description of the methods.
